# ScrollView zooming: image panning not working as intended

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on updating image compatibility to an old service and ran into a problem.

A few months ago, I've looked up how to be able to zoom and pan an image. I found the way to do this on the official Xamarin website (https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/zoom_a_scrollview/). This worked fine back then, but now it's not working as intended.

**Here's a snippet of the code I'm running:**

Modifying the size of the image to always have the width equal to the screenwidth, and the height modified using the screenwidth, to retain the image's aspects.

```
var width = image.Size.Width;
var height = image.Size.Height;
var newWidth = (GlobalSupport.ScreenWidth - 30);
var newHeight = height * newWidth / width;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(newWidth, newHeight));
image.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

Creating the imageView, adding the image to it, and setting up the scrollview and its zooming.

```
imageView = new UIImageView(
    new RectangleF((screenWidth - image.Size.Width) / 2, 
                   0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));

imageView.Image = image;

scrollView = new UIScrollView(this.View.Bounds);
scrollView.MaximumZoomScale = 4f;
scrollView.MinimumZoomScale = 1f;
scrollView.ViewForZoomingInScrollView += (UIScrollView sv) =>
{
    scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(imageView.Frame.Width, imageView.Frame.Height);
    return imageView;
};

this.View.AddSubview(scrollView);

scrollView.AddSubview(imageView);
```

I am able to zoom an image just fine, and the `UIImageView`'s width and height get modified just fine. The scrollview's contentSize is updated as well, but when zoomed I can only pan to a certain width of the image, but not the whole width. I also can't pan down. I can pan to the utmost top-left though.

Does anyone have any idea what this might be?

The image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPkgO.jpg

The image zoomed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQl61.jpg

The image panned: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR1Z3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've found the solution already. Apparently, the View.Bounds used for the parent scrollView were wrong. The scrollview was almost 2 times wider than the actual screen size, thus the panning did not work (because the width of the scrollview was wider than the actual screen size).

Solved it, by modifying the initialisation of the scrollView like so:

```
scrollView = new UIScrollView(new RectangleF(0, 0, GlobalSupport.ScreenWidth, GlobalSupport.ScreenHeight));
```